# Drupal 8 / Maestro Module : How to assign task to supervisor?

Tags: php, drupal

For my need to implement a vacation request validation workflow, I tried the Drupal Maestro workflow manager.

The need being to allow users to create their own requests and assign them to the direct supervisor. this is where I am blocked.

I created a specific module to load the supervisor object and I associated the function to the variable at the assignment task level, but in vain. An error occurs at MaestroEngine when trying to assign the task !

Would you have a complete workflow example which implements this kind of solution ? (assign the task to the initiator's supervisor).

**The variable assignment and the function definition :**

```
    <?php

    use Drupal\maestro\Engine\MaestroEngine;
    use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

    function test_module_get_current_user_supervisor( $currentUser ) {

      //$user_n_1 = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->field_n_1());
      $user_n_1 = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($currentUser->field_n_1());

      return $user_n_1;
    }
```

[Process variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzMsR.png)

PS: The supervisor is an "Entity Reference" attribute

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Erratum : The function name is : zaki_module_get_current_user_supervisor

Comment: You should initiate the process variable in the template, like supervisor_user, populate it with supervisor's username, and then in the next step assign the task by that variable. If the solution is still required (after 6 months) I can provide a full answer.